# keras mnist dataset

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, jupyter, mnist

I am learning [Neural Network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqQgED9vV7k&list=PLeo1K3hjS3uu7CxAacxVndI4bE_o3BDtO&index=7).
I was running following source code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
(X_train , y_train) , (X_test , y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

I was searching about keras mnist dataset. I found [this](https://keras.io/api/datasets/mnist/).  From that webpage I found *This is a dataset of 60,000 28x28 grayscale images of the 10 digits, along with a test set of 10,000 images. More info can be found at the MNIST homepage.* But, I was trying lot of datas. Finally, I thought to write `plt.matshow(X_train[10010])`

It outputs :
[image]

As mnist digits classification were they had *test set of 10,000 images*. So, over than 10000 should return error. While it is showing more plots. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually plotting the train set with `X_train` which has 60k samples.

Try accessing `X_test[10010]` and it will indeed raise an `IndexError`.

`keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` returns `numpy.array` objects, so you can check the shape of the arrays

```
>>> print("Train:", X_train.shape)
Train: (60000, 28, 28)
>>> print("Test:", X_test.shape)
Test: (10000, 28, 28)
```